# Devise, Cucumber and multiple IDs when logging in - registering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, devise, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having the following problem:

I have a login form on my entire site (see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app):

```
# application.html.haml
...
= form_tag new_user_session_path do
  = text_field_tag 'user[email]'
  = password_field_tag 'user[password]'
  %button Login
```

I want to test with cucumber to fill out my registration form:

```
# register#new.html.haml
= semantic_form_for resource, :url => registration_path(resource_name) do |f|
  = f.inputs do
    = f.input :email, :required => true
    = f.input :password, :required => true
    = f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true
    = commit_button("Registrierung absenden")
```

But now there is a problem - there are two fields on my page with the same attribute-id: user_email

When I try to fill the registration form with

```
# registration_steps.rb
When /^I fill in registration data$/ do |param|
  # this one selects the wrong form - loginform instead of registration form
  fill_in("user_email", :with => "blabla") 
end
```

the attribute-ids of the fields are the same and "fill_in" selects the wrong input...

How could I change the ids to work with devise? Seems too much complex for me..

Did I pointed out my problem correctly?

***UPDATE***

This is a part of my rendered registration site:

```
<html>
....
<!-- you see that both forms contain fields with the same ids! -->
<!-- so when i test f.e. with fill_in("user_login", :with => "123")
     then the wrong form will be filled out! -->
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/sign_in" method="post">
    <input id="user_login" name="user[login]" size="30" type="text" />
    <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="anmelden" name="commit">
</form>
...
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/sign_in" method="post">
    <input id="user_login" name="user[login]" size="30" type="text" />
    <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="anmelden" name="commit">
</form>
...
</html>
```

Comment: Output of `debug params` will help to understand your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem with using with_scope("123")

```
with_scope("#user_new_form") do
    fill_in("user_email", :with => "123")
end
```